# css making a list based on dynamic list

Tags: css, list, dynamic

i would like to create  a list in css, but i'm not surely know how to do it.
i have a divs with float left, their width is constant ( 240px ) always!, but their height can be dynamic.

more paramter that has to be calculated is the numbers of rows is dynamic as well, in this picture is 3 rows, but it can be 4, 5 or even 10 rows ( based on screen.width ) **so i can't use this code:**

```
<div class="row1">
    <div class="list-box"></div>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
</div>

<div class="row2">
    <div class="list-box"></div>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
</div>

<div class="row3">
    <div class="list-box"></div>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
    <div class="list-box"></div>
</div>
```

and this is the picture that i want to make in css:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/usPlB.png:

Thanks in advance,
Daniel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually can't do this in pure CSS, as you need JavaScript to be able to dynamically calculate where to place something horizontally.

However, you can use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), which works as either a standalone program, or as a jQuery plugin.